# Uncaught TypeError: document.createElement is not a function at addToIdeaList at <anonymous>:1:1

Tags: javascript

I am having this error come through.

I have the exact same bit of code higher up in my JS file and that functions fine. I have even tried copying this code to where the error code is and I still get the same error.

```
function addToIdeaList(){
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    var item = ideaBox.value;
    listItem.innerHTML = item;
    outputList.appendChild(listItem);
    loadNewCombination();
}
```

Here is the code producing the error. I really cannot work out what is wrong. Thanks to anyone who can help !

```
addToIdeaList();
javascript.js:145 Uncaught TypeError: document.createElement is not a function
    at addToIdeaList (javascript.js:145)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
addToIdeaList   @   javascript.js:145
(anonymous) @   VM365:1
```

This is the exact error message I am getting from chrome.

Comment: Post more code so we have more context. Also try to debug your code and investigate the state of the variables when using this method.

Comment: There's definitely no problem with that function. Some more context might be helpful. Can you produce a snippet here in your question that demonstrates the error?

Comment: The new title is intriguing. Can you post the anonymous function that calls `addToIdeaList`?

Comment: @AustinMullins initial title was a mistake. I switched the name of the function around a couple of times. The function is called function addToIdeaList(){. I've just been calling the function in the chrome console.

Comment: I've also added the exact error message that I'm getting frm chrome

Comment: https://github.com/alasdairjames/Idea-Maker this is a link to the full code.

Comment: Ok, sorry but I was trying to put this 'full code' into a snippet. But it makes no sense. looks like this is a work in progress.

Comment: addToIdeaList is missing in your github code.

Comment: @aseferov apologies - have pushed the latest version on there now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at your `javascript.js` file on the GitHub link that you provided and I believe the error is stemming from the following piece of code (lines 115 to 120; error is on line 118):

```
// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
randomizeBtn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  outputList = document.createElement = "ul";
  loadNewCombination();
}
```

Here you have replaced `document.createElement` with the string `"ul"`, thus making it "not a function". This line should be changed to

```
outputList = document.createElement("ul");
```

Comment: Yep that has fixed it. Thanks so much. Lessons learned are to check code when you copy it from other sources ! Also could probrably have found the answer with a search of "createElement" to check all instances of it. Thanks so much for solving.

Comment: @AlasdairMarchant Yes, that's exactly how I found it! Glad it worked! Please consider accepting the answer.